# Operation failed. Check pod logs for uninstall-runner for more details

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ce

GitLab Version 13.*

When I enable the shared runner it automatically becomes offline while the containers for runner are running in kubernetes cluster and at UI I get message as:

```
Something went wrong while uninstalling GitLab Runner

   Operation failed. Check pod logs for uninstall-runner for more details.
```

Comment: what do the logs of the runner-pod say?

Comment: + helm uninstall runner --namespace gitlab-managed-apps
Error: uninstall: Release not loaded: runner: release: not found

Comment: can you try  "helm ls --namespace $runnernamespace"? it looks like enabling the runner triggered a helm uninstall. however, there seems to be no helm release installed in the current runners namespace.